# Meaning of "dog-rodgering practices"

Tags: meaning

I'm a native Spanish speaker trying to understand this sentence:

> The it would be a dog-rodgering practices and the poisoning of badgers he would charge me with as lay cross-armed in the ruffled silk.

I looked for the rodgering's definition in two English dictionaries, in one English to Spanish dictionary, also in Google Translator and Wordreference without luck.

Hope this question is not off topic and that someone can help me.

Comment: This sentence looks like it has been machine-translated from another language. It doesn't make sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: I agree with Irene.

Comment: No - it's "dog-rogering". Unusual recasting of "roger the dog", uncommon slang for indulge in "spanish practices" (be lazy, hide behind outdated rules).

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers. Note that in British slang *roger* is a verb meaning to perform coitus with/upon someone or something else. In American English we have something similar in "screw the pooch," meaning to fail spectacularly at a task — taken from an old joke in which the drunken subject intends to go home and "feed the dog and screw the wife" but because of intoxication switches the actions with their intended targets.

Comment: @Robusto: I've no idea where *roger the dog* expression came from, or if it's related to *screw the pooch*. In my somewhat febrile imagination it denotes someone so idle,  slobby, and tightfisted that when they want sex they look to the dog rather than the girlfriend (it's cheaper and easier to open a can of dogfood than take a young lady out for dinner and a show! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like ‘rodgering’ is being used there in its crude slang sense of ‘to bugger’. Somebody who would screw a pooch or poison a badger — not a nice guy.

*Rodger* can sometimes (perhaps rarely?) be the guy’s name *Roger* — think Rodger Dodger —  but *to roger* is the more normal spelling for the verb in the crude sense.

Hm, the OED says that apparently there are three centuries’ worth of attestations of *to rodger* with a *d* in it. I hadn’t realized that.

Comment: Not necessarily just buggery. The phrase "a jolly good rogering" is used to refer to various sex acts: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+jolly+good+rogering%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a  or rodgering: http://www.google.com/search?num=20&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=8GD&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=%22a+jolly+good+rodgering%22&oq=%22a+jolly+good+rodgering%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3977l3977l0l4300l1l1l0l0l0l0l103l103l0.1l1l0

Answer (score 6):

Googling your phrase turned up only one hit, [here](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_russian/poetry_literature/679959-dogrogering.html), though unfortunately no source is given.  (**Edit**: According to the comment by Tae, the passage is from the 1999 novel *The Inflatable Volunteer* by Steve Aylett.)  It appears your version has introduced some grammatical errors.  Here is the passage in context:

> Of course if I dropped dead Eddie would have been first to steal my hair, the ideas at their root, my clothing, money, women, music, words and reputation. Then he'd start saying I did the murders. Then it would be dogrogering practices and the poisoning of badgers he would charge me with as I lay cross-armed in the ruffled silk. Praying at the dark far rear of his head my eyes don't spring open and my purpling mouth demand the evidence.

The narrator says that if he were to die, Eddie would not only accuse him of having done the murders, but also of offenses such as "dogrogering practices" (i.e. having sex with dogs; *roger*, as a verb in British slang, is approximately synonomous with *bugger* or *fuck*) and poisoning badgers.  "Cross-armed in the ruffled silk" suggests the narrator lying in a coffin, as though Eddie would make the accusations at the narrator's funeral.

I would understand accusations of "dogrogering practices and the poisoning of badgers" as over-the-top and rather absurd; the author is using hyperbole.  The point of the passage seems to be that Eddie is untrustworthy and, if the narrator were to die, would not hesitate to spread lies about him if it were to Eddie's advantage to do so.

Comment: Indeed, that's the original text, a novel by Steve Aylett, a British writer, called The Inflatable Volunteer.

Comment: And here I was convinced it was from Beckett.