# Meaning of the verb "to pooch"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, american-english

I'm familiar with the word *pooch* as a cute synonym of doggy, but here is *pooch* used as a verb:

> It was just a poorly done deal and it just so happens to be the biggest deal ever for Nasdaq and **they pooched it**, that's the bottom line here," said Joe Saluzzi, the co-manager of trading at Themis Trading in Chatham, New Jersey.

Is this a common usage of the word in US English?  Or is it just an example of a Wall Street trader abusing our language?

Full article [here](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2012/may/21/facebook-mark-zuckerberg-loses-2bn?intcmp=239).

Comment: Related: _[Meaning of “dog-rodgering practices”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58418/5822)_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first thought was that this is probably a shortening of the phrase *[to screw the pooch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screw_the_pooch)*.

> (*idiomatic*) to screw up; to fail in dramatic and ignominious fashion

But Wiktionary also has a listing for *[pooched](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pooched)* as an adjective, with no mention of the longer phrase:

> (*slang*) made unusable; broken; buggered (*British*)

I would say this is not a common use of the word in US English, but that most American readers would get the meaning here.

Comment: Well, screwing the pooch may often result in it becoming buggered.

Comment: Screwed the pooch sounds about right.  Also, there seems to be a consensus that *pooch* itself has a US origin.  Eg: http://www.guardian.co.uk/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-27673,00.html.  And I've never heard *pooched* here in the UK so I don't find the wiktionary entry very credible, as there are no quotes or citations given there.

Comment: @z7sgѪ: I just edited my answer after realizing that Wiktionary is indicating that _buggered_ is British, not _pooched_.

Comment: I first heard *pooched* from a Canadian.  I've now heard it a few times from other Americans but it seems uncommon in my experience (US midwest).

Comment: +1 screwed the pooch was my first thought having first heard it on the East Coast.

Answer (score 4):

According to OED.com, pooch exists as a verb in American Football.

> trans. To kick (a ball) a short distance towards the opposition's linemen rather than the designated receiver; to make a pooch kick. Also intr.

So it could be related to that - but *pooching* in this instance is a deliberate action, and is intended to make the ball difficult to handle. The reported mess up at NASDAQ seems to be a mistake. So I would still think this is related to [screw the pooch](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/61/messages/863.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the movie "Dogma," one of the characters mentions that a certain complication could "still pooch the deal," meaning it could still cause the plan not to work.